# Why NSURLConnection blocks my UI?

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection, nsxmlparser

I've been reading several threads and questions about this issue but I didn't find the solution.

I have some asynchronous calls performed with

```
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:anURLRequest delegate:self];
```

The problem is that I want the interface to be operative but it is blocked until the connection is finished.

Is this solved launching another thread? Where is exactly the problem?

**EDIT**

Ok, after retrieve data I parse it with NSXMLParser, that do it synchronously and blocks main thread. Is this correct? Then, maybe I need to parse in another thread. Anyone has a guide?

Comment: In which method do you perform that call ?

Comment: I'm calling it on a subview (not a table) of the root view controller.

Comment: You should probably include some more code from what you are doing. It's hard to troubleshoot without knowing when and how your connection is initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> Messages to the delegate will be sent on the thread that calls this method. For the connection to work correctly the calling thread’s run loop must be operating in the default run loop mode.

Are you sure that this code is being called on a run loop in default mode and not from a thread created by yourself with a different type of run loop mode?

Comment: I don't create any thread on any part of my app. But I don't know if the system creates another thread by itself and I miss the thing. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The UI should not be locking up when you use `connectionWithRequest`. Try creating a label in your UI and have your connection update it with the current amount of data, like so:

```
- (void)downloadContentFromUrl:(NSURL *)url {   
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10.0];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (connection) {
        receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
        self.downloadProgressLabel.text = @"Downloading...";
    } else {
        // oh noes!
    }
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [receivedData setLength:0]; 
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {   
    [receivedData appendData:data]; 
    int kb = [receivedData length] / 1024;
    self.downloadProgressLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Downloaded\n%d kB", kb];
}
```

`connectionWithRequest` does indeed run in it's own thread - no need for you to worry about this. In fact it must be started from the main thread. Check out the [NSUrlConnection](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/connectionWithRequest:delegate:) doc for more info.

Comment: More than lock the UI it delays the events chain until the download is finished. All the responders I touch responds after the download.

Comment: I try your test with the label and it isn't be updated until end of download :(

Answer (score 1):

```
+ (id)connectionWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request delegate:(id)delegate];
```

This method should create an asynchronous-request (that means that it runs in the background and it doesn't block the UI). You should check if there's another class/method in your file that blocks the UI (for example NSData's '+ (NSData *)dataWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)URL').

Comment: 0 occurrences of "dataWithContentsOfURL" in my project. Although, do you know what are the selectors that blocks UI? Maybe I have one of these in my code.

Comment: Hmm, is the UI still being blocked after de data has been load (didFinishLoading-method has been called)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it could help anyone, but I've the same problem (asynchronous URL request blocking the UI) but it was due to:

```
NSLog(@"dataReceived: %@", data);
```

in the connectionDidReceiveData method.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to update the UIProgressView.progress property. I calculated the new value like that

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    [self.progress setProgress:self.downloadedData.length / self.fileSize ];
    [self.downloadedData appendData:data];
}
```

Which doesn't work, I replaced this snippet of code with

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    self.downloadedSize += data.length;
    [self.progress setProgress:self.downloadedSize / self.fileSize ];
    [self.downloadedData appendData:data];
}
```

And now the progress view updates with no problem.